# C++ "value++" causes warning but "value+1" doesn't?

Tags: c++, compiler-warnings

The code:

```
int a = 0;
a = ++a % 5;
```

causes the warning:

```
warning: operation on 'a' may be undefined [-Wsequence-point]
a = ++a % 5;
~~^~~~~~~~~
```

with various compilers such as gcc when compiling with `-Wall`

Yet this code, works fine?

```
int a = 0;
a = (a + 1) % 5;
```

Why is this a warning, and can it safely be ignored?

Wrapping it in brackets etc. doesn't seem to make the warning go away.

Edit: For clarification, I was using C++17 compiler when seeing these warning messages.

Comment: The compiler is right. This is undefined behavior.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a = ++a % 5;
```

`a` is modified two times. Before C++11, this is undefined behavior — it is not specified that the increment is committed before the assignment. Since C++11, the side effect of the pre-increment on the RHS is guaranteed to be evaluated first, and `a` is guaranteed to be `1`.

```
a = (a + 1) % 5;
```

Here, `a` is only modified one time. The resulted `a` is guaranteed to be `1`.

---

Per comment: operator precedence does not determine the order of evaluation. Although assignment has higher precedence, the order of evaluation is still unspecified (prior to C++11).

Comment: For the sake of clearance, what am I missing here ?
https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence
Prefix increment has precedence `3` then direct assignment `16`, isn't this guaranteeing increment before assignment ?

Comment: @deimus I also wonder the same. I would definitely say a is set to a+1 first, then a is set to (a+1) % 5 later.

Comment: @deimus That’s precedence, not evaluate order.

Comment: @unlut See my previous comment.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Maybe you should include it in your answer.

Comment: @L.F. But still this looks like is a **defined** behavior since `c++11`, see rules `5` and `8` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order. That would be great is OP states which standard he is using.

Comment: @unlut Good suggestion. I have updated my answe to reflect that.

Comment: @L.F. Check my comment, your updates statement looks like is wrong.

Comment: @deimus I’m sorry. I took it for post-increment ... I have updated my answer again.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:

Before C++11: Because with `++a` you're modifying `a` while you're modifying `a` through assignment, therefore undefined behavior.

After C++11: See @L.F.'s answer.

Comment: This is not true since `c++11`, check the other answer

Comment: @deimus Thanks - answer updated.